# Which godzilla film had a hint onto Biolante?

Tags: story-identification, movie, godzilla

I remember a scene in the epilogue of a Godzilla film where a lab is seen with bio-material and a door closes with the text that it's project Biolante.

Can someone tell me which film this comes from?

Comment: [Godzilla vs. Biollante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Biollante) ?

Comment: @DoscoJones there was one film that hinted at that film by having the cells of biolante (or project biolante) shown in the epilogue of it. I searched and didnt find out which film it was that hinted at that film though (I only remember the scene)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Godzilla: Tokyo S.O.S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla:_Tokyo_S.O.S.)?

> In a post-credits scene, an undisclosed laboratory is shown with
> canisters containing the DNA of numerous kaiju. In the Japanese
> version, an unidentified voice announces that a "bio-formation"
> experiment involving an "extinct subject" is about to take place.

Comment: Please stop copying text from Wikipedia into tag wikis.  Either write proper content or don't do it.